# Get None after set_index for empty DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(get_pe(symbol, start_time, end_time), columns=['time', 'pe'])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [time, pe]
Index: []
>>> pd.DataFrame(get_pe(symbol, start_time, end_time), columns=['time', 'pe']).set_index('time', inplace=True)
None
```

Is there a way to get empty DataFrame with set index instead of `None`?

Comment: Pass at least 2 empty values so it won't return none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `None` because of the `inplace=True`, not because of the empty DataFrame:

```
In [46]: pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b"]).set_index("a", inplace=True)

In [47]: pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b"]).set_index("a")
Out[47]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [b]
Index: []
```